# How to deploy Nodejs along with angular in tomcat

Tags: node.js, angular

I have developed and application with **Angular13** + **nodejs**. How can I deploy the application in tomcat server in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NodeJS to run something like ExpressJS or another server-app, then you can only deploy your Angular13-App and need to run nodeJs on your server separately. The Tomcat server would be more suitable for java than for Angular and NodeJS.